# jQuery: Show/hide infinite loop cycle

Tags: jquery, loops, animation, opacity, cycle

I want to make a video(#videoplayer1) or an element on my webpage to visible (show for 30 seconds) then hidden (hide for 50 seconds duration) and create an infinite loop or cycle that repeats this show/hide function with given duration. 
Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Can you please add the code you are working on? If you don't show any effort on this your problem it will be difficoult for you to find someone here who will write the code for you.
Please have a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking

Answer (score 1):

```js
var showInterval = 3000;
var hideInterval=5000;
var myShow = function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log("show");
    interval = setInterval(myHide, hideInterval);
}
var myHide=function(){
console.log("hide");
 clearInterval(interval);
 interval = setInterval(myShow, showInterval);
}
var interval = setInterval(myShow, showInterval);
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that calls itself in a loop, Then you can adjust the timer how you want it

```js
 loop();
 var duration1 = 1000;
 var duration2 = 1000;
 
 function loop(){
  $('div').fadeIn(duration1, function() {
        $('div').fadeOut(duration2, loop);       
    })
 }
```

```css
div{
background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>hide/show</div>
```